# Familiar function of PATINDEX in mysql for Postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Is there any familiar function for PATINDEX of mysql for postgresql. I'm trying to make a sql like this in postgres.

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%schools%', 'W3Schools.com');
```

which throw an error:

> no function matches the given name and argument types. you might need
>   to add explicit type casts

To be more detailed, I'm trying to get seperate number part and string part of a string in Postgresql. I found example like this:

```
SELECT Section
FROM dbo.Section
ORDER BY LEFT(Section, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section)-1), -- alphabetical sort
         CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Section, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section), LEN(Section))) -- numerical
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to implement this, the example as below:

```
postgres=# select strpos('W3Schools.com','Schools');
 strpos 
--------
      3
(1 row)

postgres=# select position('Schools' in 'W3Schools.com');
 position 
----------
        3
(1 row)

postgres=# select regexp_matches('hahahabc123zzz', '(abc)(123)');
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {abc,123}

postgres=# select array_to_string(regexp_matches('hahahabc123zzz', '(abc)(123)'),' ');
 array_to_string 
-----------------
 abc 123

postgres=# select (regexp_matches('hahahabc123zzz', '(abc)(123)'))[1] as a, (regexp_matches('hahahabc123zzz', '(abc)(123)'))[2] as b;
  a  |  b  
-----+-----
 abc | 123
(1 row)
```

Do you want this?
And you can get all functions of string process here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-string.html

Comment: I'm sorry but I edited the question. can you please give another answer

Comment: @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM So you want to get a substring?Can you give some example datas?

Comment: abc123, I need to seperate 'abc' and '123'. Thanks

Comment: do you have a regex for string path? I found one for numeric path (\d+)

Comment: "abc123" is just an example ^^ but thanks for your help with regexp_matches. I'm working on it

Comment: @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM Yes, of course we can use regex in `regexp_matches`, you can improve the SQL according to your needs. :D

Answer (score 1):

Can you try [`POSITION()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-string.html) function:

```
SELECT POSITION('schools' in 'W3Schools.com');
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I edited the question. can you please give another answer

Comment: @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM I hope you need `regexp_matches()`